# vbscript WMI Using Public Member Functions (nVidia NV2)

Tags: vbscript, wmi, nvidia

I am trying to use some nVidia functions in there WMI API (attached, it is a txt file but should be renamed to chm for help file)

I am new to vbscript so can be doing something wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

arrComputers = Array(".")
For Each strComputer In arrComputers
WScript.Echo
WScript.Echo "=========================================="
WScript.Echo "Computer: " & strComputer
WScript.Echo "=========================================="

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2\NV")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM SyncTopology", "WQL", _
                                      wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In colItems
    NodeID = objItem.id
    WScript.Echo "id: " & NodeID
    WScript.Echo
Next

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2\NV")
Set SyncClass = objWMIService.Get("Sync")
if (SyncClass.toggleSource()) Then
    wscript.echo "done!"
End if
```

Next

I am actually trying to use a different function but this one is the easiest and takes no arguments.

The class is 'Sync' the function is toggleSource, should be too easy!

I get an error on line:

```
if (SyncClass.toggleSource()) Then
```

stating:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test3.vbs(28, 2) SWbemObjectEx: Invalid method Parameter(s)
```

I can query attributes in the class just can run methods :(

I can use these methods in Powershell so they should work, just can't get it working in vbscript!! AHHH...

Comment: You can't have a WMI call return immediately **and** get the results of the call at the same time.

Comment: If I try:

    myResult = SyncClass.toggleSource()

I get the same result :(